# Simple ActionScripts 3 read JSON from PHP

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to read JSON data from localhost PHP in ActionsScripts3, I found some code to do it but this code doesn't works.

PHP:

```
<?php 
$arr = array ('DATA1'=>"111",'DATA2'=>"222");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

AS3:

```
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;


var urlLoader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();

function ReadJsonPhp () :void
        {
            addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,init);
        }

function init(event:Event)
        {
            urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://localhost/asphp.php"));
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlLoaderCompleteHandler);
        }
function urlLoaderCompleteHandler(e:Event):void 
        {
            trace(e.target.data) ;
            var arrayReceived:Object = JSON.parse(e.target.data);
        }

ReadJsonPhp();
```

This code have 3 function if possible i like to use only 1 function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in one function just because it's an async operation. You make a request and then wait for some response. The AS3 code just wrong and doesn't make any sense. Here is a simple example:

```
    private var loader:URLLoader;
    private var request:URLRequest;
    private function load():void
    {
        request = new URLRequest("http://localhost/asphp.php");
        loader = new URLLoader()
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
        loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onError);
        loader.load(request);
    }
    private function onError(e:Event):void
    {
        // handle error
    }

    private function onComplete(e:Event)
    {
        trace(e.target.data);
        // keep in mind that if the Json string is invalid here will be SyntaxError exception! 
        var json:Object = JSON.parse( e.target.data );
        trace( "json.DATA1 = ", json.DATA1 );
        trace( "json.DATA2 = ", json.DATA2 );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your simple codes and your useful description.

Comment: Well you can do it in one function by passing a callback to the load function.

Comment: How to possible separate data of JSON in this code? for example trace or use variable to store data "String1=111" "String2=222"

Comment: @RafH It doesn't make any sense, I assumed that he wants not a single function but a single operation, since your suggestion doesn't really change anything. The callback will be called only after loader will complete/fail :) Also you can define a closure inside a loader function and dispatch an event (but keep in mind to avoid coupling with an external state as it will lead to memory leak.)

Comment: @AlikMiankoli Check out this spec: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html

Comment: I found solution for second question(but not in adobe reference guide, in stackoverflow). Thanks.